# Make file not moveable, copyable or deleteable?

Tags: c#

I here from CodeProject, but they don't seem to have an answer to my question. I just want a desktop file to have security permission(make the file not moveable, copyable or deletable). This is possible to do manually in the file's "properties!. I am using C#, your help is much appreciated - thanks!

As a helper said below, if it is not possible to make a readable file uncopyable...is it possible to make it not moveable and deletable?

Comment: There is no way to make a readable file uncopyable.

Comment: set the folder permissions to list folder contents only but this is also not a question for here

Comment: I'm not sure putting required files on the _desktop_ is a good design.  There are better places to put the file.  A _shortcut_ on the desktop might be acceptable, but not the file itself.

Comment: If you can remove the _Security Permissions_ of a file for any user/group, it will become just the thing u want for that particular user/group. Moreover you can look into [File.SetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these things are possible EXCEPT being uncopyable. Readable files can always be copied unless you restrict ALL copying on the system (which is a formidable task). However you can certainly prevent it from being moved or deleted.

From a file permissions perspective, you need to set the owner to an administator, then grant read-only permissions to the user in question. This will allow them to read the file but not delete or move it.

Doing so is quite simple using the `FileInfo.SetAccessControl` method in `System.IO`; [here's the documentation to help out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

Edit to add example, credit to MS for the example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace FileSystemExample
{
    class FileExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string FileName = "c:/test.txt";

                Console.WriteLine("Adding access control entry for " + FileName);

                // Add the access control entry to the file.
                // Before compiling this snippet, change MyDomain to your 
                // domain name and MyAccessAccount to the name 
                // you use to access your domain.
                AddFileSecurity(FileName, @"MyDomain\MyAccessAccount", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

                Console.WriteLine("Removing access control entry from " + FileName);

                // Remove the access control entry from the file.
                // Before compiling this snippet, change MyDomain to your 
                // domain name and MyAccessAccount to the name 
                // you use to access your domain.
                RemoveFileSecurity(FileName, @"MyDomain\MyAccessAccount", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }

        // Adds an ACL entry on the specified file for the specified account.
        public static void AddFileSecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
        {
            // Create a new FileInfo object.
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);

            // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
            // current security settings.
            FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

            // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
            fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                            Rights,
                                                            ControlType));

            // Set the new access settings.
            fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);

        }

        // Removes an ACL entry on the specified file for the specified account.
        public static void RemoveFileSecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
        {
            // Create a new FileInfo object.
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);

            // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
            // current security settings.
            FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

            // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
            fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                            Rights,
                                                            ControlType));

            // Set the new access settings.
            fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);

        }
    }
}
```